# Prevent text shadow from being on top text decoration

Tags: html, css

I want to have a text shadow and text decoration without the shadow being on top of the decoration.

HTML:

```html
<a href="" id="link">here</a>
```

CSS:

```css
#link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#link:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

main h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  text-shadow: black 3px 3px;
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Be aware that `main h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6` makes it look like you want to select those headers only in the main tag. While the correct selectors for that would be `main h1, main h2, main h3, main h4, main h5, main h6`. Otherwise you could just drop the `main` in front of `h1` if all h1 are the same anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question exactly. But I think you want to have shadow on your text and for the shadow not to be applied to the text-decoration underline.

What you could do, instead of using `text-decoration`, use `border-bottom`.

Then remove the `border-bottom` on hover

```css
#link {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
    
#link:hover {
  color: white;
  border: 0;
}
```